# How to make a web request using https in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, webclient

I have

```
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, ea) =>
        {
            var ret = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ea.Result);
            .....    
        };
        var uri = new Uri("../myrest/Login", UriKind.Relative);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

This works fine. But I want to send this request over https not plain http. I try manipulating the uri address to change the scheme to https

```
    var url = "https://localhost/myrest/Login";// hardcoded for now
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
```

But this doesnt work. It triggers the whole clientaccesspolicy.xml thingy. Presumably because the base URL is different from the url used to load the xap

I know I have the absolute path correct, if I just change the 'https' to 'http' all works ok

SL4

Comment: and you are not putting "thie whole clientaccesspolicy.xml thing" in place because...?

Comment: Because it doesn't seem like I should need it. But apparently I do

Answer (score 0):

try access your Silverlight thru HTTPS and use HTTPS login.

Comment: but then all my traffic pays the overhead of https